# cannot find import; DLL may be missing, corrupt, or wrong version. Wine kernel32.dll error?

Tags: kernel, wine

I'm trying to install hard drive wiping software that was written for windows. I have downloaded wine and get through most of the installation process until the program tries to open. It is here where I receive the error message:

```
cannot find import; DLL may be missing, corrupt, or wrong version
File "KERNEL32.dll", function "DeleteVoloumePointW" (error 0)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the specific software that you are trying to install? Have you looked at the [Wine application database](http://appdb.winehq.org/)  to see if there are suggested workarounds or if your particular software has a garbage rating?

Comment: The software I'm trying to install is active@killdisk. I have ubuntu 12.0.4 running on an old Dell Poweredge server. I checked the wine database but couldn't find any data wiping software...